# Excecuting multiple Insert statements in a batch using sqlu in Slick(Scala)

Tags: scala, slick

I currently have the following and where each individual record gets executed one at a time.

```
private var db: Option[DatabaseDef] = ....
typedRecords.foreach(publishToDatabase(_))

def publishToDatabase(record: T): Unit = {
        Await.result(runDatabaseAction(record), getQueryTimeOut(settings))
}

  private def runDatabaseAction(record: T): Future[Int] = {
    db.get.run(
      executeStreamingAction(record, settings)
        .transactionally
        .withStatementParameters(statementInit = _.setQueryTimeout(getQueryTimeOut(settings).toSeconds.toInt)))
  }

override def executeStreamingAction(record: TFFactDataIngestionMessage, settings: GSConnectorSettings):
  DBIOAction[Int, NoStream, Effect with Effect.Transactional] = {

    val sqlUAction =
      sqlu"""
          INSERT INTO ...
        """

    sqlUAction.transactionally
  }
```

The db.get.run methods doesnt accept an array of actions.

Looking for a way to publish the typedRecords at once, any idea how to convert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to chain sequence of DBIOs using monadic operators:

```
db.run(
  operation1
    .flatMap(_ => operation2)
    .flatMap(_ => operation3)
    ...
    .transactionally
)
```

if you prefer for-comprehencion:

```
// you don't have to ditch the results with _, you can do whatever you want
db.run(
  (
    for {
      _ <- operation1
      _ <- operation2
      ...
    } yield ()
  ).transactionally
)
```

or if you want to turn a `List[DBIO[A]]` into `DBIO[List[A]]`

```
db.run(
  DBIO.sequence(operations).transactionally
)
```

Comment: Do they all execute in one transaction?  Using the db.run(DBIO.sequence(operations)) getting a return type of Future[Seq[Int]] which seems to be, but wanted to confirm.

Comment: Content of `DBIO` (abstract description of your query) is run transactionaly if you tell it to through `.transactionally` method. If you don't call it, you cannot assume that it will be one transaction. In your example (`db.run(DBIO.sequence(operations))`) you didn't use it so I wouldn't assume it.